# Reverse Number Formula

Tags: functions

I'm wondering if there is a formula where a value can be read backwards. For example, if `x = 45`, then `f(x)` should equal `0.54`. If `x = 376.59` then `f(x) = 95.673`. Finally, if `x = pi, e, or any irrational number` then `f(x) = [infinity]`. Is there a mathematically formula to create these results?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the math in your questions.

Comment: If $x=\sum_{i=n}^{i=m}a_i10^i$ then $F(x)=\sum_{i=-m}^{i=-n} a_{-i}10^i$.

Comment: For non-negative integers $n$ you can write some form of recursion: $f(n)=f(n-1)+0.1$ unless $n$ is a multiple of $10$ in which case $f(n)=f(n/10)/10$ starting with $f(0)=0$. For terminating decimals $a \in (0,1)$ you can say $f(a)=m$ when $f(m)=a$.  For $n+a$ you can say $f(n+a)=f(n)+f(a)$.    You will also find that some rationals things like $f(\frac13)$ is infinite or not defined.

Comment: What do you mean by "mathematical formula"?  There's nothing wrong with defining something the way you did. (But note repeating rationals would also by infinite.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the formula is $$f(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{\lfloor10^{1-n}x\rfloor-10\lfloor10^{-n}x\rfloor}{10^n}$$

Comment: (Note that the series diverges for $x$ irrational or rational with a non-terminating decimals)